# How can I use python to read windows eventlog from a remote machine?

Tags: python

I'm working on retrieving the Windows eventlog from a remote machine using Python.

I tried the following code:

```
import win32evtlog 

server = 'aRemoteMachineHostName' 
logtype = 'System' 
hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server,logtype)
total = win32evtlog.GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hand)
```

and I get an access denied error.

Then I tried use win32security.Logon to do the authentication before I access the eventlog.
But I find in the win32security.Logon document, it says the API only supports local logon.

So, I'm a little bit stuck here. I wonder whether Python can do a remote Windows logon?
Any tips or hints will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Dumb question, maybe, but are the local machine and the remote machine on the same Windows domain?

Comment: The two machines are considered as two seperated ones, not necessarily to be in the same domain, they could be just standalone server or domain computer. But the credential for the target server is given.

Answer (score 0):

might be easier to use snmp

Comment: you MIGHT be able to expose event log via SNMP

Comment: yes, if an local agent is set, we can do a lot of things with event log. I might prefer no local agency, that will be a little easier for setup before use the function.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the user who is executing the script has the credentials to connect and read the event log, this ActiveState Recipe works for me. I've used it in a few different situations.

[ActiveState WinEvtLogViewer](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577499-windows-event-log-viewer/)